# Configure ceph block storage pool in cockpit

Tags: virtual-machines, storage, ceph, cockpit

I have a plain install on machine C with Oracle Linux 9.1 and cockpit and cockpit-machines. On machines A and B I have a ceph cluster configured which defines an rbd block storage pool for VM disks. Having copied a minimal config and the keyrings onto machine C I can "access" the ceph cluster as in the command `ceph osd lspools` on machine C returns all configured pools as expected.

In the cockpit UI however, the only options I see for configuring a new storage pool, are `filesystem` and `network file system`, nothing else.

How can I configure the existing rbd storage pool to be available to new VMs I create in the cockpit UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating rbd storage pools in the Cockpit UI is currently impossible, I found a way of creating the pool for use with libvirt. The pool is properly displayed in the UI and I can also create new volumes there.

1. Log in to your ceph admin node and create a new client token:

`ceph auth get-or-create client.libvirt mon 'allow r' osd 'allow class-read object_prefix rbd_children, allow rwx pool=mypool'`

2. Log in to your virtualization host (the machine managed with Cockpit) and configure the pool for libvirt.

`virsh secret-define --file secret.xml`
`virsh secret-set-value --secret UUID --base64 "$(ceph auth get-key client.libvirt)"`
`virsh pool-define mypool.xml`

3. The pool should now be visible in the Cockpit UI, can be activated and new volumes can be created.

The configuration files should look similar to those:

```
<secret ephemeral='no' private='no'>
  <uuid>UID</uuid>
  <usage type='ceph'>
    <name>client.libvirt secret</name>
  </usage>
</secret>
```

```
<pool type="rbd">
  <name>mypool</name>
  <source>
    <name>mypool</name>
    <host name='CEPH_MON_IP'/>
    <auth username='libvirt' type='ceph'>
      <secret uuid='UUID'/>
    </auth>
  </source>
</pool>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with cockpit but with ceph. Reading the [cockpit docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/cockpit/cockpit-kvm.html#check-the-storage-pools) I would probably choose physical disk as source, and the physical disk is a mapped rbd device. If you already have a pool dedicated for rbd usage, I would create one (or more) rbd images in required size:

```
rbd -p <pool> create -s <size> <name>
```

Then map that rbd device on the hypervisor, for automatic mapping after boot there's an example file within the `/etc/ceph` directory:

```
# cat /etc/ceph/rbdmap 
# RbdDevice             Parameters
#poolname/imagename     id=client,keyring=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.keyring
```

To enable the map after boot you need to enable the rbdmap service:

```
# systemctl enable --now rbdmap.service 
● rbdmap.service - Map RBD devices
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rbdmap.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When the rbd image is mapped to the hypervisor you should see it in `lsblk` output as an `rbd` device, or in `/dev/rbd` as well:

```
# lsblk 
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                  11:0    1  458K  0 rom  
rbd0                252:0    0   10M  0 disk

# ls -l /dev/rbd0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252, 0  9. Feb 12:18 /dev/rbd0
```

So from the hypervisor's perspective it's now a local disk which you can use to create storage pools.